# 2 different types of custom UITableViewCells in UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

in my UITableView i want to set for the first news of an rss feed a custom tableViewCell(Type A lets say) and for the other news second, third etc.. another custom tableViewCell(trype B) the problem is that the custom tableViewCell(trype A) created for the first news is reused, but curiously the number of rows between the first use of the customViewCell(type A) and the second appearance of the same type of customViewCell is not equal..

my cellForRowAtIndexPath it looks like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    int feedIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
    Feed *item = [[[[self selectedButton] category] feedsList] objectAtIndex:feedIndex + 1];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    if(feedIndex == 0){
        MainArticleTableViewCell *cell = (MainArticleTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[MainArticleTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
            [[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTag:111];
        }

        cell.feed = item;

        return cell;

    }
    else{
        NewsTableViewCell *cell = (NewsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[NewsTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier orientation:currentOrientation] autorelease];
            [[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTag:111];
        }

        cell.feed = item;

        return cell;

    }
    return nil;
}
```

the the two types of cells have different heights which is set correctly. could someone point me in the right direction on how to make the type A custom cell to appear only for the first news(not being reused)? thank you

Comment: for the Swift version of this question see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30774671/uitableview-with-more-than-one-custom-cells-with-swift)

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You should create a different cell identifier for the two styles of cell:

```
- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

int feedIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
Feed *item = [[[[self selectedButton] category] feedsList] objectAtIndex:feedIndex + 1];

static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

if(feedIndex == 0) {

   MainArticleTableViewCell *cell = (MainArticleTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[MainArticleTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier1] autorelease];
       [[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTag:111];
   }

   cell.feed = item;

   return cell;
}
else {
   NewsTableViewCell *cell = (NewsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

   if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[NewsTableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2 orientation:currentOrientation] autorelease];
       [[[cell subviews] objectAtIndex:0] setTag:111];
   }

   cell.feed = item;

   return cell;
}

return nil;
}
```

Comment: thank you it worked. do you know if it is possible to set different customcells for different sections of a tableView? section 0 will have type A and section 1 will have type B.. Thank you

Comment: found the answear.. (NSIndexPath *)indexPath has the row property also the section property that was useful :) Sorin

Comment: int feedIndex = indexPath.row;  - is good enough at first line

Comment: Very good answer. The only thing I had to find out after reading this is: It is totally okay to register 2 nibs for cells. `[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell1" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellId1]; [self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"Cell2" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:cellId2];` That solution works with Xcode 6 and iOS 8 :)

Answer (score 8):

I don't entirely understand your question, but noticed two curious things.  If you're using two different cell types you need to use two distinct cell identifiers when calling 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier'.  You're currently using the same identifier for both, which is incorrect.  Try something like:

```
static NSString *MainArticleIdentifier = @"MainArticle";
static NSString *NewsIdentifier = @"News";
```

Also, I've never seen anything like:

```
int feedIndex = [indexPath indexAtPosition:[indexPath length] - 1];
```

Why not just use:

```
int feedIndex = indexPath.row;
```

Answer (score 0):

in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
if ("Condition for cell 1") {
        cellV = ("customCell" *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"your ID cell in .xib"];

        if (cellV == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YOUR-CELL-FILENAME" owner:self options:nil];
            cellV = "OUTLET-CEll-IN-VC";
        }
    } else {
        cellV = ("customCell" *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"your ID cell2 in .xib"];

        if (cellV == nil) {
            [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"YOUR-CELL2-FILENAME" owner:self options:nil];
            cellV = "OUTLET-CEll-IN-VC";
        }
    }

[self configureCell:cellV indexpath:indexPath withClipVo:clip];

return cellV;
```