# How to increase UITableView height within ScrollView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, ios8

I have a UIViewController in swift/ios 8.

In that view I have added two UITableView (Not UITableView Controller)

I have successfully loaded data from JSON web request.

I have added these tableviews within scroll view.

Now I want to make increase the height of the UITableView to fit all the rows. I do not want the UITableView to scroll. The UIView should be scrolled, with the Scroll View.

I have tried increasing size, also tried using sizeToFit method on the table view.i

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using two separate `UITableView`s inside of a `UIScrollView`, use one `UITableView` with multiple sections.

The `UITableViewDelegate` protocol provides ways to use headers (`tableView:viewForHeaderInSection:`) and footers (`tableView:viewForFooterInSection:`) to create custom UI between the sections as needed.

Comment: Thakns Don. I have used the same technique now. But can I have different UITableViewCells for each section. Plus I need some header and footer content on the View, e.g. Title and an Image. Is this possible? and How?

Comment: Use a different reuse identifier for each custom cell type (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11659263/multiple-uitableviewcell-classes-in-one-uitableview). You can create the header and footer as headers and footers for the table sections using the above delegate methods.

Comment: Thanks Don. That was helfpful