# iPhone - Two different custom cells, with different designs, in same UITableViewController - Cells keep initial size

Tags: iphone, uitableview, tableview

I am trying to make a UITableViewController with two different custom cells. I have seen many posts, most notably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405688/2-different-types-of-custom-uitableviewcells-in-uitableview), that suggests using two different reuseidentifiers. I am doing that, and I still seem to get the size of the fist custom cell. It does not show the labels, etc... of the second cell, but the size seems to be the same. The data is displayed differently, but the cell size is the same.

Since I don't know where the problem lies, I might include more code than is necessary, so I apologize in advance.

Here is my code for the TableViewController:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    //set equal to the information in the array
    return [jsonDataArray count];
}

- (void) addHeaderAndFooter
{
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 1)];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    //[self.tableView setTableHeaderView:v];
    [self.tableView setTableFooterView:v];

}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *SCellIdentifier = @"SCell";
    static NSString *PCellIdentifier = @"PCell";

    NSLog(@"%@",indexPath);
    NSLog(@"JSONDATAARRAY: %i", jsonDataArray.count);
    NSDictionary *jsoninfo = [jsonDataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        OBPromoCell *cell = nil;
        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[OBPromoCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:PCellIdentifier];
        }

        //get required keys from dictionary and assign to vairables
        NSString *title = [jsoninfo objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *subtitle = [jsoninfo objectForKey:@"subtitle"];
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsoninfo objectForKey:@"image_URL"]];

        //download the images. This will most lilely need to be made asynchronous.... I don't think it is now.

        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];

        //fill in text to cells
        cell.CustomCellTopLabel.text = title;
        cell.CustomCellBottomLabel.text = subtitle;
        cell.CellImageView.image = img;

        return cell;
    }

    else
    {
        OBStandardCell *cell = nil;
       cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (cell == nil) {
            cell = [[OBStandardCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SCellIdentifier];
        }   

        //get required keys from dictionary and assign to vairables
        NSString *title = [jsoninfo objectForKey:@"title"];
        NSString *subtitle = [jsoninfo objectForKey:@"subtitle"];
        NSURL *imageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[jsoninfo objectForKey:@"series_image_URL"]];

        //download the images. This will most lilely need to be made asynchronous.... I don't think it is now.

        NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imageURL];
        UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];

        //fill in text to cells
        cell.CustomCellTopLabel.text = title;
        cell.CustomCellBottomLabel.text = subtitle;
        cell.CellImageView.image = img;

        return cell;
    }
}
```

Here is an image of how my storyboard is setup for reference. Again, they do have different reuseidentifiers:

[image: Storyboard]

Thank you for any help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost you have done the things. Problem is related to data showing.

You need to implement "heightForRowAtIndexPath" method of UITableView and set the height according to cell display.

```
Method:
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Hope it will solve your problem.

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks! That was it, and why I did not see that before is a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

UITableView has a property

```
@property(nonatomic) CGFloat rowHeight
```

you can set it , but it will set height for all rows in your table ,

if you want different row heights  , you should implement this method of UITableViewDelegate

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```