# Multiple Inheritance classes in a tableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm creating a tableView from a set of different inheritance classes, but i can't seem to figure out what is the best way to add them all in to a tableView, without creating multiple arrays, which isn't ideal?

Lets for instance take a classic example, how would i be able to add multiple different cat and dog objects into an tableView? what is the best way to do this?

```
class Pet {
    var id: Int = 0
    var name: String = ""

}

class Dog: Pet {
    var Type: String = ""
}

class Cat: Pet {
    var Type: String = ""
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward way is to reflect **your model** in your UI layer.
Like:

```
class PetTableViewCell {
}

class DogTableViewCell: PetTableViewCell {
}

class CatTableViewCell: PetTableViewCell {
}
```

And use then them in your table view: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1405688/2-different-types-of-custom-uitableviewcells-in-uitableview) shows usage of two different cell types in `UITableView`

Another approach is to define a protocol which describes behaviour needed from model class to be displayed in the cell, and implement it (or inherit it) in model classes.

```
protocol MyTableViewCellDisplayable {
    var Type: String
    var Pic: Image
    var Name: String
}

class MyTableViewCell {
    func displayObject(obj: MyTableViewCellDisplayable);
}

class Pet: MyTableViewCellDisplayable {
}

class Dog: Pet {
}

class Cat: Pet {
}
...
```

The choice of right solution really depends on your particular requirements.

Comment: all data in the tableView will be from the Pet class and not from subclass, is it then necessary to make subclasses?

Comment: No - from subclasses as well. They will inherit protocol implementation, probably use without modification, probably override it.

Comment: y okay i guess the main problem is going to be for instance sorting these different objects by for instance a date in the Pet Object?

Comment: No - you can put everything you want to display in something like Array<MyTableViewCellDisplayable> and sort by some property common for all model classes - better to define it in protocol as well. For sorting you might use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value

Comment: MyTableViewCellDisplayable is a tableViewCell subclass?

Comment: MyTableViewCellDisplayable is a protocol, MyTableViewCell is UITableViewCell subclass

Comment: `MyTableViewCellDisplayable` is at the moment undeclared, what do i need to declare here? sorry haven't work with this before? any guides on this or?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90725/discussion-between-petro-korienev-and-peter-pik).